# parameter pendingDynamicLinkData specified as non-null is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

```
private fun getReferralId() {
    Firebase.dynamicLinks
        .getDynamicLink(intent)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
            pendingDynamicLinkData?.link?.getQueryParameter(
                DEEP_LINK_QUERY_PARAM_REFERRAL_ID
            )?.let { refId ->
                viewModel.saveReferralId(refId)
            }
        }
}
```

[image]

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is
> null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter,
> parameter pendingDynamicLinkData
> at app.package.activity.MainActivity.getReferralId$lambda-2(Unknown
> Source:7)
> at app.package.activity.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$ANLS0uCuXrQe7RFQ5b0C-RFsBKE(Unknown
> Source:0)
> at app.package.activity.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onSuccess(Unknown
> Source:4)

version:

```
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1")
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx"
```

What is wrong here?

**UPDATE**

It happens when I update version of play-services-auth libs

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.5.1"
```

to newest version

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.0"
```

How is that even related?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's a [bug in the library](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2992) due to a play services update. To fix it, you should explicitly declare that the `pendingDynamicLinkData` is nullable.

Like this:

```
private fun getReferralId() {
    Firebase.dynamicLinks
        .getDynamicLink(intent)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData: PendingDynamicLinkData? ->
            pendingDynamicLinkData?.link?.getQueryParameter(
                DEEP_LINK_QUERY_PARAM_REFERRAL_ID
            )?.let { refId ->
                viewModel.saveReferralId(refId)
            }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Complement to @brwngrldev's answer.

## Update

The problem was fixed in a recent version of play services library (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#january_05_2022)

Check what dependencies you have in your project, and update them to the version listed in "Artifacts released on maven.google.com".

For example, in the case of the question's issue, the following dependencies need to be updated:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1"
```

## OLD ANSWER

The bug was fixed in play-services-base version (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_16_2021)

If you do not wish to explicitly set the field to nullable, you can update the  play-services library by adding these two lines to your app's build.gradle.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1'
```

Credits: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2992#issuecomment-1001847825